# How to get exact error message from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to print exact error for given ajax snippet.
Actually I am calling my .php script which returns the data fetched from database in json format.
And while running this it shows me some error 
i.e alert box of error popups, so how to find exact error over here?

```
$.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        dataType: 'json',
    // url: "store_locator.php",  
        url : "http://localhost/GoogleMaps/store_locator.php",
        data: parameters,  
        success: function(msg) {  
            //alert(msg);
            displayStores(msg);
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert("Error : "+thrownError);
        }    
    });
```

Comment: Use the network tab of the console to find the exact error message.

Comment: you can use      console.log('<your error message object>') which will show the message on console of your browser.

Comment: try using alert("Error : "+xhr.responseText);

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to debug. So in order to do that these are some things you could try:

use

```
xhr.status
```

to check the status code returned by the server which will give you a clue as to what is going on. [Status codes and meanings](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

then

```
xhr.responseText
```

may give you some additional info.

As mentioned in comments use the console to see network traffic and JavaScript errors - in IE or Chrome you can push F12 to bring up the developer tools.

To answer the question this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sk8erPeter/AGpP5/) shows how to handle the error response returned and get available details from it.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the "responseText" values of the first item of the error
function
so like
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
should show you the contents of the error